# How to prove this elementary geometry statement

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

While self-studying an elementary geometry book, I found the following claim:

> If $r$ and $s$ are lines contained in the plane $P$, then for every pair of points $A\in r$ and $B\in s$, with $A\neq B$, it holds that $\overline{AB}\setminus\{A,B\}\subseteq SP^B_r\cap SP^A_s$.

where $\overline{AB}$ is the segment that joins $A$ and $B$, and $SP^A_s$ is the semiplane of P defined by $s$ and that contains $A$, so that $SP^A_s=\{X\in P: \overline{XA}\cap r=\emptyset\}$.

The statement is evident just from drawing the configuration of points and lines, but I would like to be able to write the proof in terms of sets. How can this be done? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if they are the same line? Then which semiplane do you pick because the point is on the boundary line.

Comment: Sorry, $\overline{xP}$ was a typo, I corrected it now.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that we must assume they are different lines, because it doesn't make sense otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since P is a plane, it is a set of points with an affine structure, of dimension $2$.

There are two cases to consider: 1)$r\parallel s, r\neq s$ or 2)not.

**1st case**: $\color{red}{r\parallel s, r\neq s}$
Let $\vec P$ be the direction of $P$, with dim $\vec P=2.$

$\exists u\in \vec P,$ s.t. $\color{red}r=A+\mathbb Ru$ and $\color{red}s=B+\mathbb R$u

Then $\forall x\in P, \exists !k\in \mathbb R, \exists !\lambda \in \mathbb R$, s.t. $x-A=ku+\lambda (B-A)$

Let $P_A$ the vector space pointed in $A$. Let $f:P_A\to \mathbb R $ defined as follows : $$x\mapsto \lambda$$

$f$ is a linear form. $r=f^{-1}(0), SP_r^B= \{x\in P_A:f(x)>0\}$ since $f(B)=1>0.$

As $\color{green}{\overline {AB}}:=\{x\in P_A| \exists \lambda \in [0,1], x=A+\lambda(B-A)\}, \color{green}{\overline {AB}}-\{A\}\subset SP_r^B$

Likewise, $\color{green}{\overline {AB}}-\{B\}\subset SP_s^A$

[image]

---

**second case** :(with quite similar arguments)
[image]

> $0:=r\cap s $ , $P_0$, vector space pointed in $0$.
>  $\forall x\in P_0, \exists !(\lambda, \xi)\in \mathbb R^2, x=\lambda A+\xi B$
>  Let $f:P_0\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \lambda; g:P_0\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \xi$

> $r=g^{-1}(0), s=f^{-1}(0), \color{blue}{SP_s^A}=\{x\in P_0, f(x)>0\}, \color{orange}{SP_r^B}=\{x\in P_0, g(x)>0\}$
>  As $\overline {AB}:=\{x\in P_0| \exists \lambda \in [0,1], x=A+\lambda(B-A)\}$

$$\overline{AB}\setminus\{A,B\}\subseteq \color{green}{SP^B_r\cap SP^A_s}$$